# What do you call it when a letter extends below the word like an underline?

Tags: typography, terminology

I'm trying to search for this thing but I'm unsure what terms to use.  I see it a lot in logos.  It's where a letter, typically the last, extends down under the word like a thick underline.  Sometimes they use it as a background for more text.

[image: SuperDry T-shirt]

Comment: I don't believe there is a term specifically for this. Your best bet is probably to just search "underlined logo" or something similar. It might also be helpful to know that the part of the letter that goes below the baseline is called the *descender*

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Where this device is formed from a capital, it's called a ***swash*** and there are many font variants with "Swash Capitals". Originally it was designed to fill the space between letters<sup>1</sup>, but often now swash capitals incorporate strokes which are far more ornate or elongated than a simple space filler.

In the absence of anything better, the term might easily be applied to the stroke in the illustration.

---

<sup>1</sup> OED, 1918: *Printing.* Applied to old-style capital letters having flourished strokes designed to fill up unsightly gaps between adjacent letters.